# PhpStorm indexing all files in project and non project files

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I have noticed that PhpStorm is indexing all my files even trashed files, and it slows the performance for sure.

My question is how to make indexing only on my project files not the whole files and folders in Ubuntu?

Ubuntu version: 14.04
PhpStorm version: 2016.3.3

Comment: Not enough info provided to be sure .. but check your `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP` -- check `Include paths` -- see if `.` (dot) entry is present there. If present -- remove it.

Comment: You saved my day , Thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your "Include paths" in `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP`.

If you have `"."` (dot) entry there -- remove it.

**P.S.** AFAIK such issue was resolved in PhpStorm 2017.1.